# c# How do to convert a string into a ListView Control

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have an array:

```
string[] array = new string[] { "listView1", "listView2", "listView3" };
```

I want to clear and add items into those ListViews

How do I convert the string to `ListView` control?

Comment: Are you stuck using an array of strings there?  Seems to me you'd be better off with a generic list...

Comment: `listView.ItemsSource = array;`
Have you tried this and it should solve the propose.

Comment: can you show me how to do it

Comment: why did i get negative rating???  i am just learning c# ... sorry for my questions being vague

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using windows forms, you can get controls by name like this:

```
var listView1= (ListView)this.Controls["listView1"];
```

So with your array:

```
foreach(var item in array)
{
    var listView= (ListView)this.Controls[item];
    // Do your stuff with listView here, for example:
    // listView.Items.Clear();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help ... i modified it because my controls are nested

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your help
I got it to work by doing this

```
string[] array = new string[] { "listView1", "listView2", "listView3" };
foreach (var item in array)
{
    ListView lvw = (ListView)(this.Controls.Find(item, true).First());
    lvw.Items.Clear();
    lvw.Items.Add("Cat");
    lvw.Items.Add("Dog");
    lvw.Items.Add("Mouse");
}
```